# Ruby on Rails - jQuery javascripts as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have added this to my config/application.rb file:

`config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails application)`

and I have added this to my views/layouts/application.html.erb file:

`<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

But the prototype javascript files are being included and not the jQuery files when the pages are rendered.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the server and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I usually just add https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails as a development gem, and then run the generators. Haven't run into an issue yet.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have done, the correct files are added to my public/javascripts folder, but they are not being referenced by `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>`

Answer (score 0):

Now it is supported by default